# Как uri картинку отрисовать в canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, uri

Через `ctx.drawImage()` не получается - метод не принимает строки

Как мне `uri` преобразовать в картинку?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas'),
  context = canvas.getContext('2d');

const drawRemotePhoto = async ( canvasContext2d )=>{
  const response = await fetch( 'https://picsum.photos/200/200' ),
    blob = await response.blob(),
    img = document.createElement('img');
  
  await new Promise( resolve => {
    img.onload = ()=>{
      canvasContext2d.drawImage( img, 0, 0 );
      resolve();
    };

    img.src = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  });
};

drawRemotePhoto(context).catch( err => {
  console.log(err);
});
```

```html
<canvas>
```

Альтернативный вариант кода с тем же смыслом:

```js
fetch('https://picsum.photos/200/200')
  .then( response => response.blob() )
  .then( blob => {
    img = document.createElement('img');
    img.onload = ()=> document.querySelector('canvas').getContext('2d').drawImage( img, 0, 0 );
    img.src = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  })
  .catch( err => console.log(err) );
```

```html
<canvas>
```